# html required tag doesn't work for form submission

Tags: php, html, forms, validation, required

required tag doesn't work for the following form. why? Someone please help me. Thanks.

```
<form name="qquote" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" style="margin-left:30px">
<input required type="text" id="from" class="cleardefault from" name="from" value="From" size="8px"/>
<img src="images/arrow.png" />
<input required type="text" id="to" class="cleardefault to" name="to" value="To" size="8px"/><br />
<input type="text" id="name" class="cleardefault field" name="name" value="Name" size="26px"/><br />
<input type="text" id="phone" class="cleardefault field" name="phone" value="Phone" size="26px"/><br />
<input type="text" id="email" class="cleardefault field" name="email" value="Email" size="26px"/><br />
<input type="text" id="bedroom" class="cleardefault field" name="bedroom" value="No. of Bedrooms" size="26px"/><br />
<input type="text" id="date" class="cleardefault field" name="date" value="Moving Date" size="26px" readonly onClick="GetDate(this);"/>
<input type="submit" id="submit" class="submit" name="QuickQuote" value="" />
</form>
```

Comment: please check is `<!DOCTYPE html>` is there on the top of your page... it stands for `html5`... and `html5` supports `required attribute`...

Comment: What formation problem there? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is that you already add a value inside the textbox. Meaning there is already something in it. It thinks its filled.

If you empty the field and click the button a warning will pop-up saying that field is required.

Remove the `value=` from your form and try again.

You can also add text in front of the input fields like this:

`To: <input  type="text" id="to" class="cleardefault to" name="to" size="8px" required /><br />` with the same effect. But with working required fields.

Comment: That, that is the problem. Use a `<label>` element to provide your label, not a default `value`.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I got it already. Specially thanks to @Deja Vu

Comment: @user3398595 No problem! If this was the answer that helped you, you can accept this answer. This way it's easier for other people to find the answer for their problem.

Comment: @user3398595 click the ✓ beneath the up/down vote for a question.

Comment: @IbrahimAbdelFattahMohamed Yes, you're right! This could of course be done as well. I just figured he isn't really experienced in HTML so i just chose the easy way out. But yes, placeholders are a very good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the content of the value attribute of`<input required type="text" id="from" class="cleardefault from" name="from" **value=""** size="8px"/>`.If you need to put a value in that text box,you can put `placeholder`

ie `<input required type="text" id="from" class="cleardefault from" name="from" placeholder="From" size="8px"/>`

Comment: @user3398595 if you got the answer,pls upvote the answer and accept it

Comment: Placeholders are not an adequate tool when used instead of proper labels. Though the problem analysis is the same, @DejaVu’s answer has a better proposal for a fix.

Comment: @user3398595 there will be a tick mark coming when you place mouse pointer in the left side of the answer